# Can't get Raspberry Pi's IP address (Headless Method) Unix/OSX

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have tried everything, from nmap to AngryIP scanner to PiFinder and i cannot find the IP address. How could I go about this using a complete and total headless method - because on top of it all the HDMI to HDMI cable that I'm using doesn't work to display anything, and I can't use my MacBook as a display until I get the IP address in order to use Screen Sharing. Below is my last attempt. I need help I am really struggling. And I am a beginner to RPi stuff.

$ ping raspberrypi.local
ping: cannot resolve raspberrypi.local: Unknown host

Comment: Is your Pi connected by ethernet cable to your computer or the router?  If it's connected to the router, I found this tutorial to be very helpful: http://youtu.be/MXi-Tk1Wbpc  It's a lot more complicated (maybe impossible) to do it if you're connecting a regular ethernet cable from your pi directly to your computer.

Comment: If you have access to the router you can usually figure it out in the router interface.  Most router allow you to set DHCP reservations as well, set one for your pi and it will then always get the same IP on your local network.

Comment: `raspberrypi.local` will only work if you have a zeroconf service on the Pi (I use `netatalk`)

Comment: If you are using the ETHERNET port the MAC it uses is well known and if the RPi is on the network it can be found with: `sudo nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print ip}'` which I took from http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26105/36970 assuming that your network address are of the form 192.168.0.x, tweak that part if they are not and you have the commands available on the Mac (they are on most Linuxes)

Comment: monitors are nice, but at times one must do without.  sometimes I just ethernet pi directly to my computer and run a dhcp server on the computer.  server knows what it assigned...

Answer (score 4):

From your description I do not think the networking is alive, else nmap would've found it.

Just to make sure you can run nmap with the following options `-A 192.168.1.0/24` (where 192.168.1.0/24 is your own network) The `/24` will scan each host from `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.255`.

If it doesn't show up on the nmap scan, then I sincerely doubt that it even has networking running.

May I ask how you set up your PI before you connected the ethernet cable?

My preferred method is to do an install with HDMI so that you see what is going on and only when you have networking fully enabled to go into an ssh method for management.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have properly formatted the SD card in FAT32 format and that the raspberry pi is able to detect the SD card. If the green LED glows continuously just after power on then your SD card may not have been detected properly. Once you know see that the green LED blinks then you can confirm that your pi is able to boot. You can follow this tutorial to do a headless install https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pGSnPgYYrU .
Once the installation is complete, use port scanners or check your router to get the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your only Pi on the network and it is on the same subnet, you could try an `fping` to the complete work (`fping -g -r 1 192.168.0.0/24`; replace the 192.168.0.0/24 with your subnet). And then do an `arp -a`. The Pi will probably have a mac-ID starting with `B8-27-EB`, `DC-A6-32` or `E4-5F-01`. The `arp -a` will list the associated IP address.